# Having 4000 posts, my site is so slow

Tags: cache

My WordPress sites contains 4000 posts, and the difficulty is that I have to display all of them at one page. You know, it takes ages to do that, sometimes it causes my Firefox crash.
Could you guy give me some advice so that I can speed it up, I mean how to optimize for my site to have the fastest speed in this case.
Actually I have searched so much, but I love to hear the experiences from you guy.
Thanks so much.

Comment: It doesn't sound like a good user interface experience, to dump 4000 posts to the user at once. Why don't you use paging?

Comment: How about infinite scroll http://jetpack.me/support/infinite-scroll/

Comment: If you are going to dish me 4000 posts at once, I will definitely just leave your site. I rarely even get to the third page of a google search :-). I don't think there is much you can do to optimize such a huge query with so large amount of data. You really really have to rethink your approach. I second the idea of @BradDalton to use infinite scrolling

Comment: Actually, it is an management business. It is not adequate to use WordPress, but I had already chosen WordPress as a fault. Thanks for your suggestion of Infinite Scroll, I am now put it in use.

Comment: Loading that many posts at once is wildly inefficient. No user is going to read all 4000 pieces of content. +1 to infinite-scroll.